# Converting a datetime to a numeric representation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to convert a datetime field into a numeric representation in form of YYYYMMDD. So, my logic here is (from 2011-01-01 12:00:00.000 to 20110101) :

```
convert(int, replace(cast(getdate() as date), '-', ''))
```

According to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx ), the string representation is [always?] "YYYY-MM-DD", so I simply convert that string to an INT after removing dashes from the string.

Will this always works? Will I encounter some problems with that? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That approach can work, not sure what would happen with localization settings. If you use the built in datetime conversion function options (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)  you can avoid using the replace and not worry about locales.

Example:

```
select CAST(convert(varchar,getdate(),112) as int)
```

Comment: (Format 112 is the ISO date/time format - I prefer using it whenever I work with dates, works regardless of where I or my system is - yyyymmdd... ) Just replace getdate() with your date field. 112 will also remove the time.

Comment: Really like it. Works pretty well and is a shorter form. Thanks !

Comment: @Mike Walsh - I'm nitpicking, but maybe slightly better to use : "varchar(8)" instead of "varchar" (with implied default of length 30) in the convert function.

Comment: Perhaps nitpicking, perhaps not. The output will be an 8 and there won't be any issue of truncation or data issues. I don't believe there would be an implicit conversion issue between varchar(n) and varchar(m) but it never hurts to be explicit here :-)